# My App is working different in Samsung Galaxy Note 4 and Note 5

Tags: android, xml, layout, samsung-mobile

I have written an app for android in android studio. Everything works pretty fine. I have completed y tests in my real device (Note 5) and all emulators in Android Studio. Then, I published the app in Google Play. My friend has Note 4 and he applied the app but the layout of textboxes is very odd than my tests.

**Here is the good layout:**

[NOTE 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RU9oA.png)

**Here is the layout from Note 4:**

[NOTE 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f564w.png)

**Here is the my dimension XML files:**

mdpi

large-mdpi

hdpi

xhdpi

xxhdpi

xxxhdpi

420dpi

Both Note 4 and Note 5 have same resolution (1440x2560), same ppi (518), same screen size (5,7 inch) but as you  can see it is working odd.

In my tests, both device use xxxhdpi dimension xml. When I remove this xml version. Both of them use xxhdpi version. This time Note 4 is fine but Note 5 is behaving strange in 2K resolution. After changing the resolution to 1080p it is working fine too.

What should I do? How can I fix this problem and make the app to be working in note4 and note5?

Thanks in advance.

**Layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    tools:context="com.netas.yemekhane.FirstActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include"
        layout="@layout/content_first" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/date"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="@dimen/datefs"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/corba"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/corba"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="@dimen/yemeklerfs" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/anayemek1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/anayemek1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="@dimen/yemeklerfs" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/anayemek2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/anayemek2"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="@dimen/yemeklerfs" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/arasicak1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/arasicak1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="@dimen/yemeklerfs" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/arasicak2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/arasicak2"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="@dimen/yemeklerfs" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/zeytinyagli1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/zeytinyagli1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="@dimen/yemeklerfs" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/zeytinyagli2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/zeytinyagli2"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="@dimen/yemeklerfs" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tatli1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/tatli1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="@dimen/yemeklerfs" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tatli2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/tatli2"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="@dimen/yemeklerfs" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bonus1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/bonus1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="@dimen/yemeklerfs" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bonus2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/bonus2"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="@dimen/yemeklerfs" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/fabBGLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorTransBg"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fabLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/fab2"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/standard_10"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/standard_10"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_info_outline_black_24dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fabLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/fab1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/standard_10"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/standard_10"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_date_range_black_24dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/standard_10">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_restaurant_black_24dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**dimens.xml**

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="standard_10">7dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="fab_margin">15dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="standard_55">58dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="standard_100">108dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="datefs">24.5sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="yemeklerfs">21.5sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="date">93dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="corba">232dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="anayemek1">300.5dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="anayemek2">325dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="arasicak1">392dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="arasicak2">416.5dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="zeytinyagli1">483.5dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="zeytinyagli2">508dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="tatli1">575dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="tatli2">599.5dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="bonus1">666.5dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="bonus2">691dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="buttonmargin">461dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Comment: Please paste code of layout xml

Comment: Please, show you layout xml file.

Comment: add texts in a radioGroup and test it again look if it works or not

Comment: How can I add my xml file. I can not paste here. Sorry, I am new in stackoverflow.

Comment: @DJphy the layout and dimens XML content has been added to first post.

Comment: @technik the layout and dimens XML content has been added to first post

Answer (score 0):

using just margin with relative layout is not right, do this, 
for second textview and for upcoming textview use need to use attribute android:layout_below="@+id/" 
for eg:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/corba"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
 android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/corba"
 android:layout_below="@+id/date"
 android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" 
 android:textSize="@dimen/yemeklerfs" />
```

Comment: that did not help.  here is the result that you suggested. http://imgur.com/a/GqlNN

Comment: Ah, okay it is working, you need to do for all items in your layout, like you need to relatively arrange each child with respect to one another. And also you need to reduce the margin wrt to each child, the previously used margins wont help, since once you use layout_below attribute, the margin will start with respect to the child that is referenced. Just fiddle round with margins and attributes of a relative layout, you would get the perfect out of it. You wont have to do this if you use a linearlayout. Again its your design choice :)

Comment: Thanks DJphy. I figure out it later and I re-arranged all spaces between textviews. I did not test it in real device yet but it seems OK now. BTW, I am not a developer but I am doing  this as hobby. I have another question. Some devices has "display zoom" feature. If I change it, layout is changind again. How can I prevent that either?

Comment: Sorry but your solution did not work. I add "layout_below" tag every textbox and rearrange the spaces. Here is the result: http://imgur.com/a/pLbAT  Red rectangles are the places where the textviews should be. The app's view still fine in Note 5 but it is still odd in Note4.

Comment: um, you need to learn xml, on how to arrange child. :)
send a request on hangouts, djlegends33@gmail.com. if its imp to solve